# list box in rails - data not displayed in listbox when editing form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would be really grateful if someone could shed some light on this for me.

I have in my Rails application a form to create new books.

```
class Book:
has_many  :lnkbookauts,  :foreign_key => "LSA_BOOK_FK", :dependent => :destroy
has_many  :authors,     :through => :lnkbookauts

class Author:
has_many  :lnkbookauts,  :foreign_key => "LSA_AUT_FK", :dependent => :destroy
has_many  :books,     :through => :lnkbookauts
```

In the new.html.erb form, user can add authors by clicking on a button which displays a popup. User selects the authors from that popup and then clicks on a button which closes the popup and displays the selected author names in a listbox found in my new book form.
All this is done using javascript.

Clicking of the 'Save Book' button saves the book entry along with the authors.

The problem is When i click on the 'Edit' button, i would like the author names to be displayed in the list box on my edit form but unfortunately currently, that's not the case.

new.html.erb:

```
<p class="redLink">List of Authors:- <span><select size=5 id="book_author_ids" name="book[author_ids][]"  multiple selected="true"> </select></span>
<br/>
<%=  link_to add authors, new_author_path, :popup => ['new_window_name', 'height=400 px, width=500 px']%>
```

my edit.html.erb form also contains the same code for authors.

Is there something missing in the edit form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the edit partial where to read the `options` for that `select` from. Try putting the following inside the `<select>...</select>` tag:

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@book.authors, "id", "name") %>
```

(Where I'm assuming that `@book` is the Book instance being used to build the form, that you want the `id` of each `Author` to be the `value` field of the option, and that `Author` has a `name` method which will provide the displayed string.)

See [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion but now am getting the follwowing error message. undefined method `map' for #<Book:0x5c15f58>

Comment: In fact i don't want to display all the authors in that listbox..i just want to display the authors which have been added to the book when it was first created.

Comment: editing the authors associated with the book is done via a popup. The listbox in the new book form just displays the authors which have been selected via the popup

Comment: D'oh, made a stupid error in the code. Should read `@book.authors`. I've edited my answer. Does that work for you now?